# How can I modify the icon appearance of a custom toolbox item/user-control?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I inherited the **CheckBox** class to design a custom user control and I would like to specify the same icon image for my toolbox item like the default image that is shown for the Microsoft's WindowsForms CheckBox toolbox item.

To understand what I mean:

[image]

I think this would be possible using the **[ToolboxBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.toolboxbitmapattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)** attribute, however I'm in the need to provide the assembly that contains the user control without additional files, so I can't use a local filepath to specify a custom image and the overload where lets you specify a Type/Assembly and what it seems a resource name I really don't know how I should use it. 
Or maybe specifying the proper value in the **[ToolboxItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.toolboxitemattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)** or the **[Designer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)** attributes, however, I don't know how to do so.

If necessary, I know how to obtain the default checkbox image by downloading the **[Visual Studio Image Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt186350.aspx)** but once I have the image and after adding it to the resources of my assembly I don't know what to do with it and with the **ToolboxBitmap** attribute.

This is the code I have done to get an idea, the commented lines are just things that I'm testing randomly to try solve this issue:

```
'<ToolboxBitmap()>
'<ToolboxItem("System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem, ???")>
'<Designer(GetType(CheckBox), GetType(IComponent))>
<DesignTimeVisible(True)>
<ToolboxItemFilter("System.Windows.Forms", ToolboxItemFilterType.Require)>
<PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name:="FullTrust")>
Public Class ElektroCheckBox : Inherits CheckBox

End Class
```

PS: Please note that I have the same need to accomplish for other user controls that does not inherit from CheckBox class, so an extended help would be very gratefuly from my side if I can understand how to do the same I mean how I can specify for my toolbox item the default image of other controls like for example a Listview or a Listbox.

Comment: [MSDN has an extensive article on this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165910.aspx).

Comment: @Alex M. Thanks, that guide saved my life. So the thing to properly use that atribute is to specify the user control type and then specify the name of a embedded resource. Since I want to use the same icons as Microsoft and they are already stored as embedded resources in their controls then I missed all the steps and I just did this: **`<ToolboxBitmap(GetType(CheckBox), "CheckBox.bmp")>`** It works perfect!